# match 3 treatment groups & plot ASMD before and after weighting

Tags: r, matching

I am using TWANG to match 3 treatment groups and I could produce plot 1 and 2 (shown here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twang/vignettes/mnps.pdf ) but unfortunately I could not produce plot 3 that assesses absolute standardized mean differences (ASMD) before and after weighting)

Here is my code:

```
mnps.newtest1.ATE <- mnps(ttt_gps.3gp.Neo.Adj.dCRT ~ AGE + SEX + 
                     Race_2psW.O + CDCC_2gps01.2 + Histology_3gps +
                   TUMOR_SIZE_R + YEAR_OF_DIAGNOSIS,
                  data = testdf2, 
                  n.trees=10000,
                  interaction.depth=2,
                  shrinkage=0.01,
                   perm.test.iters=0,
                  stop.method=c("es.mean","ks.mean"),
                  estimand = "ATE",
                  verbose=F)
```

> Warning message: In ps(formula = currFormula, data = currDat, n.trees
>   = n.trees[i],  :   Optimal number of iterations is close to the specified n.trees. n.trees is likely set too small and better balance
>   might be obtainable by setting n.trees to be larger.

```
plot(mnps.newtest1.ATE, plots = 3)
```

> *****Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  :    length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array
>   extent In addition: Warning message: In is.na(e2) : is.na() applied to
>   non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'*****

Then after googling this error, I found this solution on 1 website ([length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent when using corrplot function from a matrix read from a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362420/length-of-dimnames-2-not-equal-to-array-extent-when-using-corrplot-function/43363407) ) but it does not work yet

```
plot(as.matrix(mnps.newtest1.ATE), plots = 3)
```

> Error in if (length(treatments) > 2 & x$estimand == "ATE") stop("The
>   \"treatments\" argument must be null or have length 1 or 2.") :
>   argument is of length zero

Any help will be so much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you used a `tibble` instead of a data frame for your data (i.e., `testdf2`). This can happen if you use a package in the `tidyverse` to create your data frame, like `haven`. Replacing `testdf2` with `as.data.frame(testdf2)` should solve the problem if this is the cause.

If you want a prettier display for the balance plot, I recommend using the `cobalt` package (which I wrote for this purpose, among others). After running `library(cobalt)`, run `love.plot(bal.tab(mnps.newtest1.ATE))`, which provides a plot with the same information (see below for an example with some additional options).

[image]

You can set `which.treat = NULL` to view all pairwise difference as well.

[image]

Comment: Hi Noah, how would one choose specific pairwise comparisons with `which.treat` ?

Comment: Also, I have 7 treatment arms and was trying to come up with a way to show all of the comparisons. I asked about `which.treat` above because I was thinking of doing them a couple pairs at a time but maybe something like `facet_wrap()` could work? I just don't know what to use inside the facet wrap function for this use case

Comment: See how to use `which.treat` [here](https://ngreifer.github.io/cobalt/reference/class-bal.tab.multi.html). To wrap with `facet_wrap()`, do `love.plot(.) + facet_wrap(vars(treat), ncol = 5)`. I will tell you that displaying 21 comparisons is not the best way to display balance. Using `pairwise = FALSE` will give a more useful display.